# how to handle multiple patterns in same logfile

Tags: kibana, logstash-grok

I have a logfile that i want to analyse with kibana. I wrote a Grok pattern that works and creates the fields i looking for. My problem is that the logfile has some lines that look totally different then all other regular events.

My Grok pattern only works for 99% of the lines in the log. I wan not able to find a way to let kibana just ignore those few line with a different pattern. I have tried filters or using several grok patterns but i can't get it to work.

A regular event in my logfile looks like:

12345678 foo 127.0.0.1 foo foo foo

From time to time i got an event with a different pattern in my logfile like

12345678 server down

My grok pattern %(SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{DATA:foo} aso fails because of the different patterns. How can i just ignore the other lines?

Answer (score 0):

Add this section after the grok pattern so the logstash will skip the failed logs.

```
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
    drop { }
}
```